# Removing duplicates in multigroup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iterator, multimap

I'm trying to remove elements that have the same key and value in a multimap. This is my code for now. After deleting the element, I get exception.

```
multimap<string, CStudent> m_StudentMap;
void removeDuplicates() {
    for (auto it1 = m_StudentMap.begin(); it1 != --m_StudentMap.end(); it1++) {
        for (auto it2 = next(it1, 1); it2 != m_StudentMap.end(); it2++) {
            if (it1->first == it2->first) {
                if (it1->second == it2->second) {
                    m_StudentMap.erase(it2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: don't decrement `--m_StudentMap.end()` and use `++it1`, `++it2`

Comment: Using `std::map<std::string,std::set<CStudent>>` instead of multimap would make this task unesessary. Another option is `std::map<std::string,std::vector<CStudent>>` and call `std::unique` on every element

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly right, but the trick with erasing elements in maps while iterating is to capture the new iterator returned by `erase`. I've also generalised the function so it can be used on an argument rather than being limited to `m_StudentMap`, and stopped the inner loop as soon as the keys diverge.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void removeDuplicates(std::multimap<K, V>& mmap)
{
    if (mmap.size() < 2) return;
    for (auto it = mmap.begin(); it != prev(mmap.end()); ++it)
        for (auto it2 = next(it); it2 != mmap.end() && it2->first == it->first; )
            if (it->second == it2->second)
                it2 = mmap.erase(it2);
            else
                ++it2;
}
```

You can see it run / fork it etc. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acfc863d8eb4d090).